# Count cell if "+ - 5" of other cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In my spreadsheet I have two columns of numbers (`CB` and `CC`).

In rows 53 through 94, I need to count the cell in column one (CB) if it is within 5 of the cell in column two (CC).

I thought it would be something like `=COUNTIF(CB53:CB94,"+-5" &CC53)` but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

COUNTIF() isn't sophisticated enough to do that by itself. Perhaps you could make another column (CD) equal to =ABS(CB-CC) and then COUNTIF() the new column, CD, is <= 5?

Comment: Thank you! I hated to add yet another column, but it worked out.  I have another one that I'm struggling with, that includes that counter, so I may have to pick your brain some more.  Thanks, again!

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ABS(CB53:CB94-CC53:CC94)<=5)*1)
```

If you have blank cells in this range, then try this updated formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ABS(CB53:CB94-CC53:CC94)<=5)*(LEN(CB53:CB94)>0)*(LEN(CC53:CC94)>0))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it didn't work out.  I appreciate your trying!

Comment: @JenniferGrau Hi, pls see this updated formula. I did test both before posting :)